# How to test Android ActionBar submenus?

Tags: android, testing, menu, junit, actionbarsherlock

Do anyone have any idea how to test actionbar submenu items with the android testing framework?  I'm using ActionBarSherlock.  I don't have a problem with clicking the first menu item to get the drop down menu like so:

```
    final View deleteView = (View) activity.findViewById(R.id.action_discard_trans);
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            deleteView.requestFocus();
        }
    });
    TouchUtils.clickView(TransListFragTest.this, deleteView);
```

But I get a null view when I try to get the submenu item after the drop down shows.

```
final View deleteMultiple = (View) activity.findViewById(R.id.am_delete_occurrences);
assertNotNull(deleteMultiple);
```

Here is my menu xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:com.paycheckplan="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_discard_trans"
    android:icon="@drawable/content_discard"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/discard_trans">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/am_delete_one"
            android:title="@string/action_mode_delete_one"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/am_delete_occurrences"
            android:title="@string/action_mode_delete_occurrences"/>
    </menu>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that using `solo.getView(R.id.am_delete_occurrences)` is a lot more reliable than `activity.findViewById(R.id.am_delete_occurrences)`.  A common occurrence where the solo version works and the activity reference doesn't is when you do a configuration change or you are trying to find a view within a fragment that's in the activity.